# "git --bare init" does not produce just a .git directory

Tags: git, bash

This is confusing. I've read in many places that `git --bare init` sets up the directory you're running the command from as a bare Git repository, the kind you want to use as a central repository. In particular, I read where this command produces simply an empty `.git` subdirectory. When I run this command from the GitGui bash window, I get several directories created, none of which is `.git`. Conversely, if I run `git init`, I get the `.git` directory and all of the ones that were created with the `--bare` option. Is there something wrong with my bash tool?

Comment: Could you list the other directories that are created in your question? Maybe someone can then explain what they are.

Answer (score 5):

The recommended way to use `git init --bare` is by specifying a directory name where the bare repository is stored. E.g. `git init --bare myproject.git` (it is common practice to have bare repositories end with `.git`). This will create a new folder `myproject.git` and place all the things Git needs inside of them.

If you leave the name of the repository out of the command, Git will initialize the *current* directory as the (bare) repository. So it will put all the things it needs inside the current folder.

So what you’re seeing is the correct outcome and all those files are necessary and desired for the bare repository.

Comment: Maybe that's what I need to do. I noticed that without any *.git directory, my GitGui doesn't recognize that parent folder as a valid repository.

Comment: It’s possible that your GUI cannot work with bare repositories (and frankly, there isn’t much you can/should do with them anyway). Most GUIs are primarily designed to perform the working directory related commands of Git. And since you don’t have a working directory with bare repositories (by design), it might not be that useful.

Comment: OK, I ran "git --bare init myproject.git", which set up the directory structure as you said it would, but GitGui still doesn't recognize it as a repository, i.e. I can't open it / browse to it through the GUI. Is there something about a bare repository that would not allow me to "open" it?

Comment: poke....makes sense. Must be the nature of the GUI and that it's a bare repo. Thanks.

Comment: I would expect `GitGui` to possibly recognize a bare repository as something to clone from but not something to open or operate on (and it wouldn't be unreasonable for it not to recognize it as somewhere to clone from since that's a relatively rare thing to need to do for most people).

Answer (score 4):

All those directories you see are the directories that are normally inside .git. Since there is no working copy, there's no need to separate out the regular files from the files in .git, so there is no unnecessary .git subdirectory.